# Sorting listview didn't work with 2 digits c#

Tags: c#, listview

i have problem with sorting a listview in c#, i use with code from MSDN : 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms996467.aspx .
The problem that if you have a number with 2 digits, it can't sorting the values correctly? [image]

Help please ?

EDIT:

```
public class ListViewItemComparer : IComparer
     {
         private int col;
         private SortOrder order;
         public ListViewItemComparer()
         {
             col = 0;
             order = SortOrder.Ascending;
         }
         public ListViewItemComparer(int column, SortOrder order)
         {
             col = column;
             this.order = order;
         }
         public int Compare(object x, object y)
         {
             int returnVal = -1;
             returnVal = String.Compare(((ListViewItem)x).SubItems[col].Text,
                                     ((ListViewItem)y).SubItems[col].Text);
             // Determine whether the sort order is descending.
             if (order == SortOrder.Descending)
                 // Invert the value returned by String.Compare.
                 returnVal *= -1;
             return returnVal;
         }
     }
```

and :

```
private int sortColumn = -1;
        private void listView1_ColumnClick(object sender, ColumnClickEventArgs e)
        {
            // Determine whether the column is the same as the last column clicked.
            if (e.Column != sortColumn)
            {
                // Set the sort column to the new column.
                sortColumn = e.Column;
                // Set the sort order to ascending by default.
                listView1.Sorting = SortOrder.Ascending;
            }
            else
            {
                // Determine what the last sort order was and change it.
                if (listView1.Sorting == SortOrder.Ascending)
                    listView1.Sorting = SortOrder.Descending;
                else
                    listView1.Sorting = SortOrder.Ascending;
            }

            // Call the sort method to manually sort.
            listView1.Sort();
            // Set the ListViewItemSorter property to a new ListViewItemComparer
            // object.
           this.listView1.ListViewItemSorter = new ListViewItemComparer(e.Column,
                                                            listView1.Sorting);
        }
```

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: Oki, thank you, i have added my code

Comment: You are looking for [Natural Sort](http://www.interact-sw.co.uk/iangblog/2007/12/13/natural-sorting)

Comment: You are comparing strings, so technically the code runs correctly. You should compare the values as integers to get numerically correct order.

Comment: @Steve yes , i want sorting like 1,2,3.....

Comment: @Sami, but the problem that i want sort by name (string), how can i do both ?

Comment: Never worked with IComparer, so don't know. I usually order the collection before binding. Don't know if that's a good practise or not. In your case I would likely check if the value is int or not and parse if is etc.

Comment: @WajdiGharsalli see my answer, it will do both. Follow that style for other types as well. In the link you have, there is an example of the same for `DateTime` also if you need it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the example you have linked to on MSDN, this is the code:

```
public int Compare(object x, object y) 
{
    int returnVal = -1;
    returnVal = String.Compare(((ListViewItem)x).SubItems[col].Text,
    ((ListViewItem)y).SubItems[col].Text);
    return returnVal;
}
```

That is doing a `string` comparison so your column is being sorted as a `string`. You need to modify the code so if the type is `int` or another numeric type to sort it using numbers. Here is some code:

```
public int Compare(object x, object y)
{
int returnVal = -1;
    try
    {
        // Parse the two objects passed as a parameter as a DateTime.
        int num1 =
            int.Parse(((ListViewItem)x).SubItems[col].Text);
        int num2 =
                int.Parse(((ListViewItem)y).SubItems[col].Text);
        // Compare the two numbers.
        returnVal = num1.CompareTo(num2);
    }
    // If neither compared object has a valid int, compare
    // as a string.
    catch
    {
        // Compare the two items as a string.
        returnVal = String.Compare(((ListViewItem)x).SubItems[col].Text,
                    ((ListViewItem)y).SubItems[col].Text);
    }
  // Determine whether the sort order is descending.
            if (order == SortOrder.Descending)
                 // Invert the value returned by String.Compare.
                 returnVal *= -1;
             return returnVal;

}
```

Comment: Sorry, but it's not work, compare it s not defined fot int

Comment: What does not work? You cannot just copy paste the code, try to understand the code and see what it is doing. Then tweak the code to meet your needs. Please take a few minutes to understand the code and see what the issue could be because the issue may be somewhere else.

Comment: there is no method compare for int, the good method is : num1.compareTo(num2)

Comment: Sorry I just realized that too. Made the change.